# Help needed with an equivalence relation task on natural numbers

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations, natural-numbers

I'm having a bit difficulties understanding and solving this task. I would appreciate any help on how you can solve tasks like this.

Here is the task:

> Let ~ be an equivalence relation on the natural numbers, and let $E$ be $[0]$, ie equivalence class to $0$.
>
> 1. Prove that E is not equal to the empty set
> 2. Prove that all natural numbers $x$ and $y$ that are elements of $E$ are such that $x$ ~ $y$.
> 3. If $[x] = [y]$, then $x$ ~ $y$? If yes, give a proof for it, if no, give a counterexample.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Regarding $(2)$ that's actually what's written in my textbook, I just did a translation that's all. Wierd...

Comment: @Dabbish: What does it say in the language of your textbook?

Comment: It's written in norwegian, but that's exactly what it says in english. Norwegian text: "Bevis at alle naturlige tall x og y som er elementer i E, er slik at x ~ y." Makes no sense, but if you copy and paste this in google translate, you'll see it's the same as above

Comment: Your translation isn’t quite right. It should be: Prove that all natural numbers $x$ and $y$ that are elements of $E$ are such that $x\sim y$. I’ll fix it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, consider what three properties an equivalence relation has, and note that $$E=\{z\in\Bbb N:0\sim z\}.$$ One of the three properties of an equivalence relation will allow you to prove the claim.

For the third one, we will use the same property of an equivalence relation. You want to show that if $$\{z\in\Bbb N:x\sim z\}=\{z\in\Bbb N:y\sim z\},$$ then $x\sim y.$

I believe that the second one should read "Prove that all natural numbers $x,y$ which are elements of $E$ are such that $x\sim y.$" That is, we must show that if $x,y\in E,$ then $x\sim y.$ This time, we will be using the other two properties of equivalence relations to prove it.

---

**Edit**: As you know, a binary relation $R$ is said to be an *equivalence relation* on a set $A$ if and only if it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive on $A$. In particular, this means:

- For all $x\in A,$ we have $x\:R\:x.$ ($R$ is reflexive on $A$.)
- For all $x,y\in A,$ **if** $x\:R\:y,$ **then** $y\:R\:x.$ ($R$ is symmetric on $A$.)
- For all $x,y,z\in A,$ **if** $x\:R\:y$ and $y\:R\:z,$ **then** $x\:R\:z.$ ($R$ is transitive on $A$.)

Now, suppose that $R$ is any binary relation, $A$ any set. For each $x\in A,$ define:

$$[x]_{A,R}:=\{z\in A:x\:R\:z\}$$

Let's use this notation to rewrite the definitions of reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity of $R$ on $A$:

- For all $x\in A,$ we have $x\in[x]_{A,R}.$ ($R$ is reflexive on $A$.)
- For all $x,y\in A,$ **if** $y\in[x]_{A,R},$ **then** $x\in[y]_{A,R}.$ ($R$ is symmetric on $A$.)
- For all $x,y,z\in A,$ **if** $y\in[x]_{A,R}$ and $z\in[y]_{A,R},$ **then** $z\in[x]_{A,R}.$ ($R$ is transitive on $A$.)

Observe then that for any $x\in\Bbb N,$ we have $[x]:=[x]_{\Bbb N,\sim}.$ Do you see, then, which of the three properties immediately tells us that $[0]\ne\emptyset$? We will use this property again to show that if $[x]=[y],$ then $y\in[x]$ (why is this true?), and so $x\sim y$ by definition.

For $(2),$ we will use the other two properties. In particular, we want to show that if $0\sim x$ and $0\sim y,$ then $x\sim y.$

Comment: Regarding $(2)$ that's actually what's written in my textbook, I just did a translation that's all. Wierd...

Comment: Incidentally, are you familiar with the notation $\omega,$ or are you used to $\Bbb N$? Perhaps something else altogether?

Comment: I'm familiar with the second one

Comment: Yes, @Brian M. Scott gave me an helping hand there. I edited the post regarding the $(2)$ Thank you.

Comment: I found what I believe to be your assignment (or at least, one worded precisely the same), and I believe I have translated it more accurately. Take a look and see if it makes sense to you. Let me know if you have any trouble working out the proofs, or if you're uncertain you are proceeding correctly, and I can try to clarify/critique things for you.

Comment: $(3)$: We assume, as given, that ~ is an equivalence relation on S and that x ~ y. To show that $[x] = [y]$, it is enough to show that $[x] \subseteq [y]$ and $[y] \subseteq [x]$. To show that $[x] \subseteq [y]$, suppose $z \in [x]$. (We need this assumption by showing that $z \in [y]$.) The definition of $z \in [x]$ and that $z$ ~ $x$. Then we have $z$ ~ $x$  and $x$ ~ $y$. Since ~ is transitive, we have $z$ ~ $y$. The definition of $[y]$ gives that $z \in [y]$. Then we have shown that $[x] \subseteq [y]$. To show that $[y] \subseteq [x]$ is equivalent.


I hope it's understandable.

Comment: Also I'm not sure on $(1)$ and $(2)$. Would appreciate any answer here.

Comment: It appears that you're actually trying to prove the *converse* of $(3)$ (which the assignment I found also includes, so that's fine). It looks like you are on the right track, but let me see if I can make it clearer. To start with, we suppose that $z\in[x],$ meaning that $z\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\sim z.$ Since $x\sim y,$ then $y\sim x$ (why?), so since $x\sim z,$ then $y\sim z$ by transitivity. Thus, $z\in[y]$ by definition, proving that $[x]\subseteq[y].$ By similar reasoning, $[y]\subseteq[x].$ Thus, if $x\sim y,$ then $[x]=[y].$

Comment: More generally, suppose that $R$ is an equivalence relation on a set $A$. What properties (aside from transitivity) must $R$ have? Can you state all the properties explicitly in mathematical terms?

Comment: Hmm.. I think it would need the properties for symmetric and reflexive relations? Else it wouldn't become a equivalence relation right? Regarding what the properties would be, I'm not so sure

Comment: Yes! An equivalence relation is one that is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. One of these properties *immediately* shows that $[x]:=\{z\in\Bbb N:x\sim z\}$ is non-empty for every $x\in\Bbb N$. We can also use the same property to show that if $[x]=[y],$ then $x\sim y$. **Hint**: What *must* be an element of $[y]$?

Comment: Wouldn't that be $z$? Or I'm I wrong here?

Comment: What is $z,$ though? All we're assuming is that $[x]=[y]$ for some $x,y\in\Bbb N.$ We don't know how the relation $\sim$ is defined on $\Bbb N,$ only that it is an equivalence relation. Given that, there is only one element of $\Bbb N$ we can be *certain* is an element of $[y].$

Comment: Ahh alright, thanks alot, but what about $(1)$ and $(2)$. What would the answers be there?

Comment: As I said, we'll use one of the three properties to prove both $(1)$ and $(3),$ and we'll use the other two properties for $(2).$ Which property did you end up using for $(3)$?

Comment: The transitive property

Comment: I'm afraid the transitive property will be of no use in proving $(1)$ or $(3)$. I've expanded my answer to hopefully make it easier to see what is going on.